# Jar file failing to execute

Tags: command-line, java, jar

I have a jar file located at `/home/username/Documents/program.jar` and when I open the terminal and type `java -jar ~/Documents/program.jar` I get the following readout:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: amidst/Amidst : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

The command `java -version` outputs the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.8) (7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.121-b00, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Most likely you are trying to run a jar that was compiled with a higher JDK version than installed on your current system. Solution is most likely to install the latest java version.

For an easy method, check this link: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: In terminal, type `java -version` and include the output in your question.

Comment: question has been edited

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer make your comment into an answer because it solved my problem

Comment: Happy I could help you out ChristianF97.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java -version` command confirms that you're running an older version of **openjdk** *(and you may have mixed in a little Oracle Java 7... choose one, not both)*. Here's the current version information for **openjdk**...

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.10.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Start `Software Updater` from the Unity dashboard and update your software.

---

If you'd rather use **Oracle Java**, another way to update your java version (specifically if you're using a release less than 16.04) is to use the ppa from the webupd8 team using the following steps:

1) Open terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

2) Enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

3) Enjoy java 8 :)

Side note - Last package (`oracle-java8-set-default`) may not be necessary to install